# How do I hide the text that the user enters into a password JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a class that asks for a username and password to autenticate a user in the application.

Inside it, I have 2 **JTextField** objects, one for the username input and one for the password input.

```
JTextField userNameTextField = new JTextField(20);
JTextField pswdTextField = new JTextField(20);
```

It works fine but my problem is that, when the user writes the password in the pswdTextField, the password is shown inside it. I want to hide it by showing a dot, asterisk or similar for each letter that makes up the inserted password.

How is this done?

Comment: Use a `JPasswordField`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a JTextField, use a JPasswordField for your pswdTextField